Unable to withdraw whETH from Psyfi whETH Covered Call Vault
I am unable to withdraw my whETH from Psyfi's vault. Attempts to do so show the following error message on Phantom "This transaction reverted during simulation. Funds may be lost if submitted". Solscan says "(Program Error: "The Program Expected This Account To Be Already Initialized")".
Psyfi's website says "AnnouncementVaults and Lending are currently in withdraw-only mode. Please withdraw all assets before Pyth Oracle deprecation on 30th June 2024." I did not notice it until now.
Please help. Thanks
